# Two scripts and only one script is working properly

Tags: javascript, onload

I have loaded two scripts in functions.php in wordpress theme. Both are loading properly but only one is working. I noticed that in first (script which is not working) is executing everything without code fragment which is in window.onload function. In second script I have also window.onload function but this is working. I also noticed that when I reverse the order (first script will be below the second in HTML) then first script is working and second not (because the first one is loading later).

Comment: Use `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', func )` instead of `window.onload`.

Comment: Still the same. I also use window.onscroll after window.onload so I don't know is it change something.

Comment: I changed window.onscroll on window.addEventListener('scroll', function) and it's working now. Thank you!